# SSB4 Timber with Multiple Villagers

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

In SSB4, if multiple Villagers are playing in the same game and they all grow trees with Down+B, are each of them able to cut each other's trees down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible from personal experience.

The wiki confirms that yes, it is possible.

> A Villager can interact with another Villager's sapling and tree,
>   provided he is on the correct move stage-- any Villager's watering can
>   is able to make another Villager's sapling grow to the tree form, and
>   a Villager can also chop down a tree that isn't his, turning the tree
>   into his own attack. Each player can only have one sapling on the
>   field at any given time, however, though saplings can be planted right
>   onto another sapling.

http://www.ssbwiki.com/Timber